# Jenkins communication with VSTS failed due to "unsupported curveId"

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins with Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). It was perfectly working fine for more than a year. All of a sudden I got this error and it stopped working with the error message `Unsupported curveId: 29`.

Full stack trace:

```
Building in workspace C:\Jenkins\jobs\TFS\workspace
Querying for remote changeset at '$/proj1/proj1' as of 'D2016-12-05T18:36:30Z'...
FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unsupported curveId: 29
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unsupported curveId: 29
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:157)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.extractChangesetNumber(Project.java:272)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:268)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:284)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.recordWorkspaceChangesetVersion(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:311)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:260)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1325)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:682)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:587)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1543)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unsupported curveId: 29
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.VersionControlExceptionMapper.map(VersionControlExceptionMapper.java:50)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayer.queryHistory(WebServiceLayer.java:1888)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.queryHistory(WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.java:1427)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient.queryHistory(VersionControlClient.java:4678)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.MockableVersionControlClient.queryHistory(MockableVersionControlClient.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:65)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:33)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:153)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.TransportException: Unsupported curveId: 29
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:743)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:475)
    at ms.tfs.versioncontrol.clientservices._03._RepositorySoap12Service.queryHistory(_RepositorySoap12Service.java:1502)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayer.queryHistory(WebServiceLayer.java:1872)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported curveId: 29
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:597)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2528)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1312)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:513)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:464)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:376)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:590)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Something changed regarding your SSL certificate; it's specifying an algorithm that Jenkins doesn't recognize.

Comment: Was that on the Windows 2008 Server or in the Network? As far as I know there is no update, or change in the server. Does the network configuration change changes the SSL?

Comment: Would you suggest anything to change on SSL?

Comment: Can you upgrade the Java SDK version on your Jenkins server and then try again?

Comment: @user2683269 How do you get that error? Queue a build with the source in VSTS, trigger Jenkins build after your VSTS build or related to Team Foundation Server Plugin for Jenkins?

Comment: I get this error as soon as I click the build job. Even before trying to authenticate to TFS.

Comment: @user2683269 What's the version of TFS Plugin for Jenkins? Try to upgrade it.

Comment: I Have 4.1.0, I believe that's the latest one.

Comment: @user2683269 What's the Java SDK version installed on the server? Have you tried upgrading it to the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tries didn't work. This one worked finally.

1) Reinstall Latest version of Jenkins ( different folder than it was previously installed)
2) Update all the plug-ins.
3) Create New Jobs ( Exactly same name as there were before)
4) Copy each job's config files one by one to the new Jobs.

It worked great.